# Trouble with has_parent query containing scripted function_score

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two document types, in a parent-child relationship:

```
"myParent" : {
  "properties" : {
    "weight" : {
      "type" : "double"
    }
  }
}

"myChild" : {
  "_parent" : {
    "type" : "myParent"
  },
  "_routing" : {
    "required" : true
  }
}
```

The `weight` field is to be used for custom scoring/sorting. This query directly against the parent documents works as intended:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "function_score" : {
      "script_score" : {
        "script" : "_score * doc['weight'].value"
      }                 
    }                                                                       
  }    
}
```

However, when trying to do similar scoring for the child documents with a `has_parent` query, I get an error:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "has_parent" : {
      "query" : {
        "function_score" : {                                                    
          "script_score" : {
            "script" : "_score * doc['weight'].value"
          }
        }
      },
      "parent_type" : "myParent",
      "score_type" : "score"
    }
  }
}
```

The error is:

> QueryPhaseExecutionException[[myIndex][3]: query[filtered(ParentQuery[myParent](filtered(function score (ConstantScore(*:*),function=script[_score * doc['weight'].value], params [null]))->cache(_type:myParent)))->cache(_type:myChild)],from[0],size[10]: Query Failed [failed to execute context rewrite]]; nested: ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[No field found for [weight] in mapping with types [myChild]];

It seems like instead of applying the scoring function to the parent and then passing its result to the child, ES is trying to apply the scoring function itself to the child, causing the error.

If I don't use `score` for `score_type`, the error doesn't occur, although the results scores are then all `1.0`, as documented.

What am I missing here? How can I query these child documents with custom scoring based on a parent field?

Comment: <ahem>bounty?</ahem> :)

Comment: @DrTech Patience, Iago, patience ;)

Comment: :D /me waits patiently

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This I would say is a bug: it is using the `myChild` mapping as the default context, even though you are inside a `has_parent` query. But I'm not sure how easy the bug would be to fix. properly.

However, you can work around it by including the `type` name in the full field name:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/t/myChild/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_score * doc[\"myParent.weight\"].value"
          }
        }
      },
      "parent_type": "myParent",
      "score_type": "score"
    }
  }
}'
```

I've opened an issue to see if we can get this fixed [#4914](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4914)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I assume there's no added cost to referencing the parent from the script's child context, since they will always be in the same shard?

Comment: Correct - no extra cost.

Comment: What's strange is that Martijn v Groningen linked to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/martijnvg/8639841) from the [ES discussion topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/elasticsearch/w7zgncPYMVY/K3qRlpd7TQ0J) that couldn't repro the issue. I had trouble seeing what the difference was. Anyway thanks again.

Comment: The difference is that he didn't specify the type in the URL, so it searched the mappings for all types for a field called `weight`. Because we've specified the type in the URL, it only searched `myChild`, not `myParent`

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are trying to score `child` documents based on a field in the `parent` document and that the function score should really be the other way round.

To solve the problem my idea would be to store the parent/child relation and the score with the child documents. Then you would filter for child documents and score them according to the `weight` in the child document.

An example:

```
"myParent" : {
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}

"myChild" : {
    "_parent" : {
        "type" : "myParent"
    },
    "_routing" : {
        "required" : true
    },
    "properties": {
        "weight" : {
            "type" : "double"
        }
    }
}
```

Now you could use a `has_parent` filter to select all `child` documents that have a certain `parent` and then score them using the `function score`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "function_score" : {
                    "script_score" : {
                        "script" : "_score * doc['weight'].value"
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "has_parent": {
                    "parent_type": "myParent",
                    "query": {
                        "term": {
                            "name": "something"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if `parent` documents were blog posts and `child` comments, then you could filter all posts and score the comments based on `weight`. I doubt that scoring `childs` based on `parents` is possible though I might be wrong :)

Disclaimer: 1st post to stack overflow...

Comment: "you are trying to score `child` documents based on a field in the `parent` document" Are you saying the design is wrong, or explaining the error? The error doesn't make sense to me because the `script_score` is within the `has_parent` query, so I would expect it to operate on `parent` documents.

Comment: The `has_parent` query returns `child` documents that have a certain parent. So the error `No field found for [weight] in mapping with types [myChild]` is basically saying that the `script_score` function is trying to access the `weight` field, which is only present in `myParent`. So yes, you need to change the desing.

Comment: Like I said, the `script_score` is *within* the `has_parent`, so I would expect `doc` to reference `myParent` in the script.

Comment: No. `has_parent` will match `child` documents so there you only have `child` documents, not `parents`. What you might mean is a `has_child` query, that will match `parent` documents with a certain `child`. But again, you then get `parent` documents and _not_ `child` documents and you cannot score `child` documents based on `parents`. Imagine 10 `childs` to one `parent`: which of the childs should be the most relevant?!

Comment: "`has_parent` will match `child` documents having a certain `parent`" Exactly - and it finds those certain parents with a nested `query` of its own, *which queries parents*. I'm trying to score the children based on the score of those certain parents in the `has_parent`'s `query`, which is based on a script that I would *expect* to work on `parent` documents.

Comment: "you cannot score child documents based on `parents`" That's exactly what I'm trying to do so please explain why.