# ElasticSearch Function score referring to nested attribute while other, same named attribute happens to exist in top level too

Tags: function, elasticsearch, nested-attributes, scoring

I am trying to calculate the `_score` of the document as a sum of IDs of my nested docs.

Here is the mapping:

```
PUT /test/property/_mapping
{
"property": {
  "properties": {
     "destination_id": {
        "type": "long"
     },
     "rates": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
           "id": {
              "type": "long"
           },
           "end_date": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
           },
           "start_date": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

and here is my query:

```
GET /test/property/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "rates",
               "score_mode": "sum",
               "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                     "functions": [
                        {
                           "script_score": {
                              "script": "doc['id'].value"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It works fine and score is calculated properly when I don't have field `id` in my main (top level) document.
Something unexpected happens though as soon as I add document constructed that way:

```
POST /test/property/3
{
   "destination_id": 1,
   "id": 12,
   "rates": [
      {
         "id": 9,
         "end_date": "2014-10-15"
      },
      {
         "id": 10,
         "end_date": "2014-10-20"
      }
   ]
}
```

after that all my `_scores` are reduced to **0**.

Seems like the top attribute kind of 'overshadows' the nested ones…!?
anyway that I think shouldn't happen as I explicitly specify `nested` path, right?

1. Can anybody validate if that's the expected behaviour or bug?

and most importantly:

2. Is there a way to correctly refer to the nested attribute in such situations? or really anything else I could do to prevent situation where adding one such document would not break the searches that were working before??

Comment: Possibly related: [Trouble with has_parent query containing scripted function_score](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289149/trouble-with-has-parent-query-containing-scripted-function-score)

Comment: It turned out to be the same issue. Using `"doc['rates.id'].value"` solved the problem for me. Thanks @PaulBellora!