# Passing dynamic value to script query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two mappings in my index. One of them stores some amount in different currencies and other stores current conversion rate. Records in each look like this:

```
http://localhost:9200/transactions/amount
```

```json
[{
    _index: "transactions",
    _type: "amount",
    _id: "AVA3fjawwMA2f8TzMTbM",
    _score: 1,
    _source: {
        balance: 1000,
        currency:"usd"
    }
},
{
    _index: "transactions",
    _type: "amount",
    _id: "AVA3flUWwMA2f8TzMTbN",
    _score: 1,
    _source: {
        balance: 2000,
        currency:"inr"
    }
}]
```

and

```
http://localhost:9200/transactions/conversions
```

```json
{
    _index: "transactions",
    _type: "conversions",
    _id: "rates",
    _score: 1,
    _source: {
        "usd": 1,
        "inr":62.6
    }
}
```

I want to query the data from `amount` and apply current conversion rates from `conversions` in a single query and get result.

I tried using scripted query and was able to convert the data based on passed params like:

```
GET _search
```

```json
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "script_fields" : {
        "test1" : {
            "script" : "_source.balance * factor",
            "params" : {
                "factor"  : 63.2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However in my case passed params are to be fetched from result of another query.

I want to visualize my data in Kibana in common currency. Kibana supports scripted queries. As per my knowledge all visualizations in Kibana can correspond to a single elastic search query so I don't have an option to do multiple queries.

I also tried exploring the possibility of using https://www.elastic.co/blog/terms-filter-lookup and adding some dynamic fields to each document in result set. However I don't think term filter allows that.

Comment: what if you build a plugin that would have access to a database where you store data from other queries?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, you're trying to always plot transactions in USD, you could try the approach described in [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289149/trouble-with-has-parent-query-containing-scripted-function-score):

In essence:

1. Model your data parent-child with each `conversions` document being a parent of all child `transactions` document in the same foreign currency.  (And `conversions` having a standard fieldname like `"conversion_divisor": 62.6`)
2. Include a `has_parent` query clause for all relevant currency conversions.
3. Use a `function_score` (`script_score`) query to access the foreign currency multiple in each parent and generate a `_score` for each transaction by dividing the transaction amount by the foreign currency `conversion_divisor`.
4. Plot the `_score` in Kibana