# Elastic Search, Nest. functional sorting

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

I'm building a filter page, with facets etc, which works as it should.
Now the our customer has a request to, basically "Be able to decide which sorting the items comes out in". 
Each product is decorated with a Product Display Order, and is in a Product Line.

We got these example Product Display Orders:
 1. Featured Item
 2. Core Item
 3. Spare Part
 4. Utility

And these Product Lines:
 1. Hammers
 2. Saw
 3. Wood

and the sorting is like this:
Sorting should firstly be based on Product Display Orders, secondly by product lines, thirdly Alphabetically.
So all products which is a **Featured Item** is listed first, and all these Featured Items is then sorted by their **product line**, and if some product are in the same Featured Item and Product Line, then its alphabetically.

The challenge is: I can't just get the sorting of Product Display order items and product lines as a number on the product, i only got a name/id.

We've thought of Boosting based on if the product are in the different categories, but it seems a bit messy.

OR

See if it possible to have some logic in the Sorting. 
Sort by productDisplayOrder:
1. featured, 2. core Item ... 
Then by ProductLines:
1. Hammers, 2. Saw ... 
Then by Name DESC.

Which way is the best way to have this sorting, is it possible to give this logic to elastic, if it is a match and then sort it. Or are we needed to twist the boosts of product?

Hopefully this makes sense for you. 
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1). Quickest/Best performing solution would be to create new/separate integer fields for `productDisplayOrder` and `ProductLine` and then use those in your sort criteria as described (after reindexing and validating the the data is indexed as expected).

Option 2) If you want more nuance than described (eg higher scoring matches can 'break through' the ordering ceiling described) then you can explore using a [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to implement a custom scoring strategy that takes `productDisplayOrder` and `ProductLine` into consideration in generating an overall match score.

Option 3). If you can't change the mapping and reindexing your data, you can use [Script-Based Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) to generate sorting values from the currently indexed productDisplayOrder/ProductLine text using a script (eg Groovy).   Keep in mind that query performance will be worse than the first two options.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I know the most optimal option is the first one, but we can't know if the field contains the right value at searchtime, because if the sorting of ProductDisplayOrder can be changed, whichout our products being reIndexed. 
With the Function score Query, can i make 100% sure to control the score as i want?

Comment: Sounds like you need your client to generate a dynamic script to use in the query.  (Either of the last two options.)

Comment: Thanks alot Peter. 
We will try to go with option 1, and reindex when the sorting node is edited. Then we might need to reindex all products, but the sorting shouldn't change often. So rather have it to be slower at the editors than being slower at the customers.

Comment: There's a fourth option that would make changing the order at the "sorting node" very cheap, *but it comes with a memory premium and limitations on sharding strategy*.  You would model your data  parent/child with the "sorting nodes" being the parent (with products as children).  Then you could use a `function_score` query to model your sort as a scoring script based on values in parent and child.  Option 1 is probably still a better approach, but read here to learn more:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289149/trouble-with-has-parent-query-containing-scripted-function-score